# .net core webapi route attribute regex with /

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-core, routes, routeattribute

I am trying to find a way to match a route when request contains multiple path and URL always end with /end

For example:

domain.com/api/path1/path2/path3/end

domain.com/api/path1/path2/path3/path4/end

I tried `[Route("api/{p:regex(([[\\w-]]*\\/){{1,}})}end")]` but this didn't work.

Any recommendation?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I tried this but in[Route("api/{p:regex(([[\\w-]]*\\/){{1,}})}end")] this doesnt work :-(

Comment: Would you edit your question to add the code you used, which didn't work as expected?

Comment: Done that thank you

Answer (score 3):

regex pattern must be as below:

```regex
^(?:[a-z0-9.]+(\/))*end
```

> Note that in the `C#` language "\" is the operator character. So you must use `\\` instead of `\`.